# How can i Pass Variable from flask) o HTML without render template?

Tags: python, html, flask, parameter-passing

I'm new to using Flask and I've just been trying to pass a variable  to web pages. I know how pass variable in render_template method

but now I am trying a realtime streaming app. It uses different methods like .responses and yields

the flask code for streaming webcam is given below

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def get_frame():
    video=cv2.VideoCapture(0) #this makes a web cam object

while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    imgencode=cv2.imencode('.jpg',im)[1]
    stringData=imgencode.tostring()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
        b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n'+stringData+b'\r\n')

del(video)

@app.route('/calc')
def calc():
return Response(get_frame(),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='localhost', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

and template is

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
 <img src="{{ url_for('calc') }}">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now I need add a label on my template like `<label>{{ value }}</label>>`

I have calculated the variable value from flask and I can print it on the console
but now I need to pass that value to a label on the same template that is streaming the video.
please help

Comment: wait so you want to pass the variable after the page has loaded?

Comment: yes i need to pass the variable after the page is loaded
trying to create a realtime object detection from  webcam
so i would like to print the object class on a label along with the video streaming

Comment: After the page is loaded, you'd need to use javascript to perform any updates to the page. The javascript would communicate with the server periodically to update the page.

Comment: Then need to use java script and ajax. Make an ajax post to the route, then send the data to to the javascript ajax then use javascript to update the value. I can help you with it in ten minutes, eating rn

Comment: sorry if i am asking a stupid question. the html page is continuously updating the image frame source for displaying the video right? without any scripts it updates the image source? so cant we use that method ?

Comment: You can use this for it. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: I am not sure how sites Like youtube do it. You could inspect their page to figure it our

Comment: i need to use webcam for realtime video streaming :(,  the above code is for videos

Comment: it looks like you are trying to do the same thing done [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/02/opencv-stream-video-to-web-browser-html-page/) so maybe follow along with him

Comment: i am able to stream the video on the webpage. i followe the above link for that.
on the above there is only one image source on the web. i would like to add an label . i  able to calculate the the value on the console from flask app. but  i need the pass that value to the label tag on the template page

Comment: add a label to the video? or to the webpage? can you past a link of page? and circle the label

Comment: no not to the video . to the webpage that is displaying the video stream.

 {<html>
 <head>
 <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title><br>
 </head><br>
 <body><br>
 <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
 <img src="{{ url_for('calc') }}">
 </body>
 </html>
}

here there is only a image source on the page
i need to add an label 
with <label> tag of html  the of displaying label must be a string value that i passed from the flask program.(just like giving value for above img src)

sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Yeah so just use ajax. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FLASK APP.py**

```py
# This route accepts request against the url http://domain_name/change_label
# You could add the argument, method=["POST"], 
# so the route only accepts post request against that url.
@app.route("/change_label")
def change_label():
    #Return the text you want the label to be
    return "New Label"
```

**JAVASCRIPT_FILE**

```js
function change_label(){
  // Create xhttp object
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // Listen for the response of your xhttp object
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // If the request is 200 aka successful, set the text of 
      // the label to the response text of the xhttp request
      document.getElementById("Id of the label").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  // Open a post request with the xhttp object. 
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://domain/change_label", true);
  // Send the post request
  xhttp.send();
}
```

**HTML FILE**

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
     <script src="link_to_javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
     <img src="{{ url_for('calc') }}">
   </body>
 </html>
```

Sorry if its hard to understand, i am very bad at explaining things, my brain is just not wired normally

Comment: Good first contribution. Your answer could be improved by added some explanation text.

Comment: @DontBe3Greedy
i am sorry i don't have enough knowledge about this
i also have trouble to explain my question

actually i got solution when we display a single image on the web with help of code

{ return render_template("index3.html", user_imagesrc = full_filename ,user_labelsrc=userlabel)}

but this  cant use when i have stream the webcam on the html page instead of displaying a single image

any way thanks for your contribution i will try to understand it

Comment: don't return a template. just add a javascript code, and call it whenever you need to update the page

Comment: @DontBe3Greedy
where will i place the label tag on the html file??

Comment: yeah put the label tag where ever you want in the html file. give it an id

Comment: label is not loading :(

Comment: @DontBe3Greedy
 hello thanks very much Its loaded when the "POST" is changed to "GET" on The script file 
But i used a button for calling the function
i need to change the value of label dynamically without any click event so where will i call the function? is there any event for label for this purpose?

Comment: ok at last got it :) 
i used window.setInterval(change_label, 1000); for continuously calling the function
but Browser gets slow on streaming :( may be due to accesing multiple function contents from flask

thanks very much for your help